# How do I make the photos from a users photoalbum load faster into a collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, phasset

I am trying to load the photos from a users local photo album into a  `UICollectionView`. When the app starts it takes a long time for the collectionView to load. I have tried indexing the project and found that the slowest part stems from where the photos are being pulled. Below is the highlighted code from the index

Flagged Code From Index

```
 let imageView = cell.imgView
        let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
        requestOptions.isSynchronous = true
        requestOptions.deliveryMode = .fastFormat
        let scale = min(2.0, UIScreen.main.scale)
        let requestImageSize = CGSize(width: cell.bounds.width * scale, height: cell.bounds.height * scale)
        PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: fetchResult.object(at: indexPath.item) , targetSize: requestImageSize, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: {
            image,error in
            if let error = error{
                print(error)
            }
            self.imageArray.append(image!)
            imageView.image = image!
            imageView.clipsToBounds = false
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        })
```

Entire Project Code

```
import UIKit
import Photos

class ViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,UICollectionViewDataSource,GreedoCollectionViewLayoutDataSource {

    var imageArray:[UIImage] = [UIImage]()
     var collectionViewSizeCalculator:GreedoCollectionViewLayout?

    var collectionView:UICollectionView! = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 2.0
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        let CV = UICollectionView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        CV.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return CV
    }()


    var fetchResult: PHFetchResult<PHAsset> = PHFetchResult()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.collectionViewSizeCalculator = GreedoCollectionViewLayout(collectionView: self.collectionView)
        self.collectionViewSizeCalculator?.dataSource = self
        self.collectionViewSizeCalculator?.rowMaximumHeight = self.collectionView.bounds.height / 3;
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5.0
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 5.0
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0)
        self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
        //End Of new Greedo Stuff in ViewDidLoad()



        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.register(customPhotoCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        self.collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        self.view.addSubview(collectionView)


        setUpLayout()
        fetchAssets()

        let photos = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
        if photos == .notDetermined {
            PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({status in
                if status == .authorized{
                    print("permission granted")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.fetchAssets()
                        self.collectionView.reloadData()
                    }
                } else {
                    print("permission not granted")
                }
            })
        }


    }

    func setUpLayout(){
        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

    }

    func fetchAssets(){
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
        fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)
    }



    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! customPhotoCell

        let imageView = cell.imgView
        let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
        requestOptions.isSynchronous = true
        requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
        let scale = min(2.0, UIScreen.main.scale)
        let requestImageSize = CGSize(width: cell.bounds.width * scale, height: cell.bounds.height * scale)
        PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: fetchResult.object(at: indexPath.item) , targetSize: requestImageSize, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: {
            image,error in
            if let error = error{
                print(error)
            }
            self.imageArray.append(image!)
            imageView.image = image!
            imageView.clipsToBounds = false
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        })
        cell.layer.masksToBounds = true
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        cell.backgroundColor = .white
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return fetchResult.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 5.0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 5.0
    }



    //Greedo Size for itemAt
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return self.collectionViewSizeCalculator!.sizeForPhoto(at: indexPath)
    }

    func greedoCollectionViewLayout(_ layout: GreedoCollectionViewLayout?, originalImageSizeAt indexPath: IndexPath?) -> CGSize {
        if (indexPath?.item)! < fetchResult.count{
            let asset = fetchResult[(indexPath?.item)!]
            return CGSize(width: asset.pixelWidth, height: asset.pixelHeight)
        }
        return CGSize(width: 0.1, height: 0.1)
    }

    //New stuff
    var lastOffsetY:CGFloat = 0
    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        lastOffsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    }
    func scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if(scrollView.contentOffset.y > self.lastOffsetY){
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
                self.collectionView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -50)
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}



class customPhotoCell:UICollectionViewCell{

    var imgView:UIImageView = {
        let imgV = UIImageView()
        imgV.backgroundColor = .orange
        imgV.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return imgV
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        print("Inside of init")
        self.addSubview(imgView)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        imgView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        imgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        imgView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


}

extension UIImageView{
    func fetchImage(asset: PHAsset, contentMode: PHImageContentMode, targetSize: CGSize) {
        let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
        options.version = .original
        PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: targetSize, contentMode: contentMode, options: options) { image, _ in
            guard let image = image else { return }
            switch contentMode {
            case .aspectFill:
                self.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            case .aspectFit:
                self.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            }
            self.image = image
        }
    }
}

extension UIImage{
    func resizeImageWith() -> UIImage {
        let aspectRatio = CGFloat(self.size.width / self.size.height)
        let newWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        let newSize = CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newWidth/aspectRatio)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, true, 0)
        self.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: newSize))
        let  newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return newImage!
    }
}
```

Additional Layout Code

```
protocol GreedoSizeCalculatorDataSource {
    func greedoSizeCalculator(_ layout: GreedoSizeCalculator?, originalImageSizeAt indexPath: IndexPath?) -> CGSize
}

class GreedoSizeCalculator {
     //private var _sizeCache = [AnyHashable: Any]()
    private var sizeCache = [IndexPath:CGSize]()
    private var leftOvers:[CGSize] = [CGSize]()
    var lastIndexPathAdded:IndexPath?


    var dataSource: GreedoSizeCalculatorDataSource?
    var rowMaximumHeight: CGFloat = 0.0
    var isFixedHeight = false
    var contentWidth: CGFloat = 0.0
    var interItemSpacing: CGFloat = 2.0


    func sizeForPhoto(at indexPath:IndexPath?)->CGSize{
        print("I made it rowHeight: \(rowMaximumHeight)")
        if let indexPath = indexPath{
            if sizeCache[indexPath] == nil{
                lastIndexPathAdded = indexPath
                computeSizes(at:indexPath)
            }
        }
        var size: CGSize? = sizeCache[indexPath!]
        if((size?.width)! < CGFloat(0.0) || (size?.height)! < CGFloat(0.0)){
            size = CGSize.zero
        }
        return size!
    }

    func clearCache(){
        self.sizeCache.removeAll()
    }

    func clearCache(after indexPath:IndexPath?){
        sizeCache.removeValue(forKey: indexPath!)

        for existingIndexPath in sizeCache.keys{
            if indexPath?.compare(existingIndexPath) == .orderedDescending{
                sizeCache.removeValue(forKey: existingIndexPath)
            }
        }

    }

    func computeSizes(at indexPath:IndexPath?){
        var photoSize = dataSource?.greedoSizeCalculator(self, originalImageSizeAt: indexPath)
        if (photoSize?.width)! < CGFloat(1) || (photoSize?.height)! < CGFloat(1) {
            // Photo with no height or width
            print("Photo has no height or width")
            photoSize?.width = rowMaximumHeight
            photoSize?.height = rowMaximumHeight
        }
        print("The photo size at index: \((indexPath?.item)!) is \nwidth: \((photoSize?.width)!), height: \((photoSize?.height)!)")
        leftOvers.append(photoSize!)
        print("Index:\(indexPath?.item) leftOvers.count: \(leftOvers.count)")
        var enoughContentForTheRow = false
        var rowHeight:CGFloat = rowMaximumHeight
        var widthMultiplier:CGFloat = 1.0
        //Calculations For Variable HeightGrid
        var totalAspectRatio:CGFloat = 0.0
        for leftOver in leftOvers{
            print("current aspect ratio: \(leftOver.width/leftOver.height)")
            totalAspectRatio += leftOver.width/leftOver.height
        }
        print("totalAspectRatio: \(totalAspectRatio)")
        //Aspect Ratio Calculation how to find the height of the row!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        rowHeight = CGFloat(contentWidth)/CGFloat(totalAspectRatio)
        print("rowHeight: \(rowHeight)")
        enoughContentForTheRow = rowHeight < rowMaximumHeight

        if enoughContentForTheRow {
            var availableSpace: CGFloat = contentWidth
            print("Available space: \(availableSpace)")
            var index: Int = 0
            for leftOver in leftOvers{
                var newWidth:CGFloat = floor((rowHeight*leftOver.width)/leftOver.height)
                print("new width: \(newWidth)")
                newWidth = min(availableSpace, newWidth)

            //add the size into the cahce
                self.sizeCache[lastIndexPathAdded!] = CGSize(width: newWidth, height: rowHeight)
                availableSpace -= newWidth
                availableSpace -= self.interItemSpacing
                // We need to keep track of the last index path added
                self.lastIndexPathAdded = IndexPath(item:(lastIndexPathAdded?.item)!+1,section:(lastIndexPathAdded?.section)!)
                index += 1
            }
            leftOvers.removeAll()
        }
        else{
            // The line is not full, let's ask the next photo and try to fill up the line
            computeSizes(at: IndexPath(item:(indexPath?.item)!+1,section:(indexPath?.section)!))
        }
    }


}

protocol GreedoCollectionViewLayoutDataSource {
    func greedoCollectionViewLayout(_ layout: GreedoCollectionViewLayout?, originalImageSizeAt indexPath: IndexPath?) -> CGSize
}

class GreedoCollectionViewLayout:GreedoSizeCalculatorDataSource {
    var dataSource: GreedoCollectionViewLayoutDataSource?
    var rowMaximumHeight: CGFloat = 0.0
    var isFixedHeight = false

    var collectionView:UICollectionView?
    private var _greedo: GreedoSizeCalculator?
    var greedo: GreedoSizeCalculator? {
        if _greedo == nil {
            _greedo = GreedoSizeCalculator()
            _greedo?.rowMaximumHeight = 200
            _greedo?.isFixedHeight = false
            _greedo?.dataSource = self
        }
        return _greedo
    }

    init(collectionView: UICollectionView?) {
        self.collectionView = collectionView
    }

    func sizeForPhoto(at indexPath: IndexPath?) -> CGSize {
        var contentWidth:CGFloat = (self.collectionView?.bounds.size.width)!
        var interitemspacing:CGFloat = 2.0
        let layout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout

        if layout != nil {
            contentWidth -= (layout?.sectionInset.left ?? 0.0) + (layout?.sectionInset.right ?? 0.0)
            interitemspacing = (layout?.minimumInteritemSpacing)!
            layout?.minimumLineSpacing = 5.0
            layout?.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5.0
        }
        greedo?.contentWidth = contentWidth
        greedo?.interItemSpacing = interitemspacing
        return (greedo?.sizeForPhoto(at: indexPath))!
    }

    func clearCache() {
        greedo?.clearCache()
    }

    func clearCache(after indexPath: IndexPath?) {
        greedo?.clearCache(after: indexPath)
    }

    func rowmaximumHeight() -> CGFloat {
        return (greedo?.rowMaximumHeight)!
    }

    func setRowMaximumHeight(_ rowMaximumHeight: CGFloat) {
        greedo?.rowMaximumHeight = rowMaximumHeight
    }

    func greedoSizeCalculator(_ layout: GreedoSizeCalculator?, originalImageSizeAt indexPath: IndexPath?) -> CGSize {
        return dataSource!.greedoCollectionViewLayout(self, originalImageSizeAt: indexPath)
    }


}
```

Comment: use fetchLimit to avoid loading entire phAssets at single time. Go batch by batch to get back the assets at runtime when it required. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phfetchoptions/1624761-fetchlimit

Comment: @iTag Thank you for your response. I have tried changing the `fetchOptions.fetchLimit = 1` just to assess the speed but still the program loads very slow. Any idea on where else the lagging may be stemming from.

Comment: it because of synchronous way of fetching the image assets. Its blocking the viewdidLoad. Try asynchronous and check whether view is appearing or not first after that try to add some loader to indicate the user image is getting loaded.

Comment: Recommend you look into this as well https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phcachingimagemanager.  Per Apple: "Provides methods for retrieving or generating preview thumbnails and full-size image or video data associated with Photos assets, optimized for batch preloading large numbers of assets. "

Comment: @iTag Thank you for your help I tried changing the requestOptions.isSynchronous = false  and putting the `PHImageManager.requestImage()` on the global `global().async` thread but the program still seems to load the photos slow. Did I implement your suggestion correctly.

Comment: @CodeBender Thank you for your suggestion I switched over all my image requests to `PHImageManager()` and implemented a `StartCacheing` instance although the program still runs slow as it loads the images into the `UIcollectionView`